# Как применить функцию к списку файлов в ООП

Tags: php, ооп

Изучаю ООП и затормозил на следующем моменте.

У меня есть класс, который отвечает за вывод списка файлов.
Пример

```
$files = new FilesList();
$filesList = $files->getFiles($currentPath);
```

Метод getFiles создает массив со списком файлов по пути $currentPath.

Например

```
[
  ['type' => 'file', 'name' => '1.jpg'], 
  ['type' => 'dir', 'name' => 'some_dir'], 
  ['type' => 'file', 'name' => '2.png']
]
```

Я могу вывести этот список просто через foreach.

```
foreach ($filesList as $file) {
    if (is_array(($file)) && isset($file['name'])) {
        echo sprintf('<div>%s</div>', $file['name']);
    }
}
```

Но теперь встала задача, напротив каждого файла добавить ссылки удалить, переименовать

Как в ООП решается подобная задача?

Я хочу создать новый класс, например, FilesTools.

Но не могу понять, как мне связать 2 класса теперь?

Буду благодарен за любые советы!

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mkdir.php   https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.rmdir.php https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php  непонятно какую задачу вы хотите решить через ООП ?!

Comment: @ArchDemon, так он архитектурно организовать, а не какие функции использовать.

Comment: Это всё очень далеко от ООП. чтобы было хоть немного объектно, в первую очередь должен быть класс-прототип, у которого два наследника - файл и каталог. то есть никакого 'type' => 'dir', 'name' => 'some_dir' быть не должно. должно быть $file->name. И вот у этого объекта должны быть _методы_ удалить, переименовать и что там еще

Comment: Ответ обновлён.

Comment: а по моему он просто хотел вывести html-ссылки удаления, переименования))

Comment: @Qwertiy, да вы правы. Меня интересует именно архитектурный момент. То есть, взаимодействие сущностей в контексте ООП.

Comment: не путайте кислое с пресным. У вас класс, который представляет из себя древовидную структуру каталогов и файлов. Он знать не должен ни о каком html от слова совсем. Рисованием красивых интерфейсов должен заниматься другой объект. В который, конечно же, нужно передать структуру каталогов

Answer (score 0):

Тебе не надо 2 таких класса. Нужно нечто, что умеет получать список, удалять и переименовывать.

Если хочется делать методы нестатическими, можно в качестве состояния хранить genm в инстансе и дольше работать с ним.

Можно сделать два класса - один для каталога и один для файла. Тогда логично их наследовать от базового с общей функциональностью.

```
FsEntry
  name: string
  rename(newName: string): void
  delete(): void
  isSymLink(): boolean

Directory extends FsEntry
  getDirictories(): Directory[]
  getFiles(): File[]
  createDirectory(name: string, deep: boolean): boolean /* создана или уже была */

File extends FsEntry
  read(): byte[]
  write(data: byte[], flags: string): void
  isFifo(): boolean
```

Comment: Ну можно и одним классом. Добавить флаг `isDirectory`

Comment: @ArchDemon, можно, но скорее всего двумя лучше, потому что они довольно разные. Читать каталог как массив байт возможно, но требуется разве что программе дефрагментации. Искать у файла подкаталоги - не требуется никому. А вот всякие isSymLink уже должны быть флагами в базовом классе.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/class.directoryiterator.php чтобы не переизобретать велосипед

Comment: @ArchDemon, ну классы для работы с файлами есть в большинстве языков :)

Comment: @Qwertiy, мне нравится твое решение, но как будто не хватает класса, который будет возвращать листинг файлов и директорий.  Сейчас в методе getFiles($currentPath) я использую while($file = readdir(...)) {$result[] = $file} Как мне это изменить лучше?

Comment: @ArchDemon, по ссылке класс дает информацию о директории. А мне как раз следующий шаг нужно, как к этому списку добавить ссылки Удалить / Переименовать напротив каждого элемента?